Cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
This is my code:
use std::collections::HashMap;
use crate::ast::ASTNode;
use std::fmt;
use crate::utils::Value;
use crate::lang::{get_built_in_functions, BuiltInFunction};

impl fmt::Display for Value {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Value::Number(n) => write!(f, "{}", n),
            Value::String(s) => write!(f, "{}", s),
            _ => write!(f, "{}", "Unsupported value!"),
        }
    }
}

pub struct Interpreter {
    pub variables: HashMap<String, Value>,
    pub built_in_functions: HashMap<String, Box<dyn BuiltInFunction>>,
}

impl Interpreter {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Interpreter {
            variables: HashMap::new(),
            built_in_functions: get_built_in_functions(),
        }
    }

    pub fn evaluate(&mut self, node: &ASTNode) -> Value {
        match node {
            ASTNode::Number(value) => Value::Number(*value),
            ASTNode::Variable(name) => {
                self.variables
                    .get(name)
                    .cloned()
                    .expect("Undefined variable!")
            }
            ASTNode::String(value) => Value::String(value.clone()),
            ASTNode::Assignment { variable, expression } => {
                let value = self.evaluate(expression);
                self.variables.insert(variable.clone(), value.clone());
                value
            }
            ASTNode::FunctionCall { name, arguments } => {
                // Clone the function reference first to avoid holding any borrow
                let function = {
                    let func_ref = self.built_in_functions.get(name);
                    func_ref
                        .expect(&format!("Undefined function: {}", name))
                        .clone()
                };

                // Evaluate arguments after resolving the function borrow
                let evaluated_args: Vec<Value> = {
                    let mut results = Vec::new();
                    for arg in arguments {
                        results.push(self.evaluate(arg));
                    }
                    results
                };

                // Call the function
                function
                    .call(evaluated_args, self)
                    .unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Error calling function {}: {}", name, err))
            }
            ASTNode::BinaryOperation { left, operator, right } => {
                let left_value = self.evaluate(left);
                let right_value = self.evaluate(right);

                match (left_value, right_value) {
                    (Value::Number(left), Value::Number(right)) => match operator.as_str() {
                        "+" => Value::Number(left + right),
                        "-" => Value::Number(left - right),
                        "*" => Value::Number(left * right),
                        "/" => Value::Number(left / right),
                        _ => panic!("Unsupported operator!"),
                    },
                    _ => panic!("Binary operations are only supported for numbers!"),
                }
            }
            _ => unimplemented!(), // Delegate other cases to loops or functions
        }
    }
}

I am new to rust and I really got stuck at these errors:
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/interpreter/core.rs:58:38
   |
48 |                     let  func_ref = self.built_in_functions.get(name);
   |                                     ----------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
58 |                         results.push(self.evaluate(arg));
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
64 |                 function
   |                 -------- immutable borrow later used here

And:
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/interpreter/core.rs:64:17
   |
48 |                       let  func_ref = self.built_in_functions.get(name);
   |                                       ----------------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
64 | /                 function
65 | |                     .call(evaluated_args, self)
   | |______________________----_____________________^ mutable borrow occurs here
   |                        |
   |                        immutable borrow later used by call

Any idea why I get this error and how can I fix it?

It's a kindness if you can strip out the irrelevant code and create a [mre]. Preferably one that runs on the playground. That makes it easy for us to see what you're seeing and test out changes. Here's what I came up with: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=47c1631549b0bfeea0a5716a5c6019b7.

@cdhowie can you please form a complete answer so I can accept it ?

let function = {
    let func_ref = self.built_in_functions.get(name);
    func_ref
        .expect(&format!("Undefined function: {}", name))
        .clone()
};

In this block, func_ref has type Option<&Box<dyn BuiltInFunction>>.  When you call .clone() you are therefore calling this on &Box<dyn BuiltInFunction>.  However, Box<T> is only Clone when T is, and dyn BuiltInFunction is not Clone.  Since Clone is not object-safe, we can categorically say that Box<dyn _> can never be cloned (via Clone).
So why does this code compile?  Because &T implements Clone for any T.  You're actually cloning the shared reference, which in this context is exactly the same as not calling .clone() at all!
There's a few ways I can see for you to easily fix this.  I list them here in order of "cleanliness" -- I would prefer the first solution to the others.

You never actually change self.built_in_functions anywhere.  If this map truly never, ever changes, then you can just make a global LazyLock, providing &'static HashMap that can be shared.  Something like static BUILT_IN_FUNCTIONS: LazyLock<HashMap<String, Box<dyn BuiltInFunction>>> = LazyLock::new(get_built_in_functions);.
You could change the HashMap to store Arc<dyn BuiltInFunction> instead.  Cloning the Arc would give you a handle to the inner function that is independent of the lifetime of *self.
You could wrap Interpreter::variables in RefCell, and change Interpreter::evaluate() to take &self.  In my opinion this is the least clean solution.

